# How do I exclude certain email folders from being searched in Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, windows-search, windows-desktop-search

Email searches in Outlook 2013 work as expected. I am trying to refine it by excluding certain folders by default. I was hoping I could uncheck certain folders in Control Panel > Indexing Options > Outlook. Unfortunately, the checkbox is for Outlook itself. I can either search Outlook or not. There is no refinement beyond that. Is there another way to exclude searching of specific folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either Advanced Search or create a Search Folder that will include only required folders and search against this Search Folder.

Comment: Hmmm... And what happens if you create a Search Folder specifying only folders a, b and c (clicking Browse and without any Criteria)?